# Morphia: inheritance not handled properly?

Tags: mongodb, inheritance, morphia

I have a class that implements an interface. Why are the arraylist contents not stored in the database? Here is some code to illustrate the problem.

The class

```
@Entity
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

@Id
@Indexed
public String id;

public String someField;

public MyClass(String id, String someField){
    this.id = id;
    this.someField = someField;
}
}
```

The interface

```
public interface MyInterface {

@Embedded
public List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Test code

```
@Test
public void test() {
    testInheritance();
}

public void testInheritance() {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass("test", "someField");
    myClass.myList.add("wow");
    MyClassDao dao = new MyClassDao();
    dao.save(myClass);
}

public class MyClassDao extends BasicDAO<MyClass, ObjectId> {

    public MyClassDao() {
        super(MyClass.class, MorphiaManager.getMongoClient(), MorphiaManager.getMorphia(), MorphiaManager.getDB().getName());
    }
}
```

Result in DB

```
{
"_id" : "test",
"className" : "gr.iti.mklab.simmo.util.MyClass",
"someField" : "someField"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces can only declare method signatures and constants (`static final` variables). What you want to use is an abstract base class from which you inherit.

Additional observations from your code:

- The `id` should be ob the type `ObjectId` and is automatically indexed, you don't need the `@Indexed`
- Attributes should be `private` or `protected` and you need to provide getters and setters for them
- You need a default no-arg constructor in your entity class